# How do I skip files which I don't have permission to read/access when using scandir(), to avoid all the logged errors?

Tags: php, windows, permissions, scandir

I use `scandir()` to search through dirs on the computer. I have also tried `DirectoyIterator` with the *exact* same result (it appears to use `scandir()` internally). Some sub-dirs apparently have special permissions, for they pollute my error log with things like:

```
scandir(C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration,C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration): Access is denied. (code: 5)
```

I don't need to search through that dir, but `scanddir()` does its thing without me being around to do any checks such as `is_readable` or `continue` based on the dir name or something like that.

Who knows how many other dirs I don't have "access" to? Naming them one by one could easily prove to be a nightmare, which is why I just want to skip those which would log an error. But even if I wanted to name them one by one, I can't, since `scandir()` does its thing with apparently no means to configure it. (That I can tell from the manual.)

Comment: So now you have deleted the previous 2 copies of this question. Well done. One of which someone actually tried to help you with

Comment: FYI: just because a question receives an answer does not mean that it is ineligible for other answers or prevent you from receiving other help.

Comment: Please mind what you say in the comments unless you'd like to earn a trip to banned camp.

Comment: Start by telling us why you are using PHP to search a windows PC. Give us something other than I get errors to work with.

Comment: Explain why you are scanning into `C:\Program Files` as well. We could come up with a usable work around, if we know what we were trying to work around

Comment: I seem to remember someone suggested you try `glob` instead of `scandir` in one of the previous instances of this question. **Did you look into that at all?**

Answer (score -1):

You can use `is_readable('C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration')` to check if you have permission. If not you'd need to make sure the directory has read privileges.

Check this link : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.is-readable.php